# Grouping data for view form- LOOPS, IF

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5.3

How would I go about setting up my controller/view so that all the services under a particular category are grouped together? (A SINGLE DATABASE TABLE called USER_SERVICES)

That is, represent the view the below...

CATEGORY: Building-cleaning services and property management services

-We manage properties

CATEGORY: Air transport services of passengers and freight, except transport of mail

-Take a flight

CATEGORY: Computer and related services

-Server maintenance

CATEGORY: Computer and related services

-Web Development

As follows (notice the last 2 services grouped together):

CATEGORY: Building-cleaning services and property management services

-We manage properties

CATEGORY: Air transport services of passengers and freight, except transport of mail

-Take a flight

CATEGORY: Computer and related services

-Server maintenance

-Web Development

My controller is setup as follows:

```
public function index(){

$user_services=User_service::latest("updated_at")->get();

return view ("services.index", compact("user_services"));

}
```

My view (index blade) is as follows:

```
@extends("app")

@section("content")

<h1>Services available</h1>

<hr/>

@foreach($user_services as $user_service)     

<article>

<h3>

CATEGORY:  {{ $user_service->service_category }}

</h3>

<!-- To see how to categorize this listing -->

<h4>

{{ $user_service->service_name }}

</h4>

</article>

@endforeach

@stop
```

I've tinkered around with the foreach loop and if function but to no avail so far.

Database (table) schema is as follows:

-id

-user_id

-service_name

-service_description

-service_category

-created_at

-updated_at

Comment: order by service_category instead of updated_at, then at every loop check if the category has changed, if it does, you can print the new header.

Comment: Thanks! @ggg See how I did it below:

Comment: I would have done it differently, but hey, if it works for you.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks! @ggg. This is how I did it:

I set up my Controller (index function) as follows

```
public function index(){

    $categories=User_service::distinct()->select("service_category")-   >orderBy("service_category")->get();

    $servicesList=User_service::select("service_category", "service_name")->latest("updated_at")->get();

    return view ("services.index", compact("categories", "servicesList"));


}
```

I then setup my index view (blade) as follows:

```
@extends("app")

@section("content")

<h1>Services available</h1>

<hr/>

@foreach($categories as $category)     

<article>

<h3>

CATEGORY:  {{$category->service_category}} 

</h3>

@foreach($servicesList as $list)

@if($list->service_category==$category->service_category)

<h4>

{{ $list->service_name }}

</h4>

@endif

@endforeach

</article>

@endforeach

@stop
```